# "Unknown option", "Bad command" on configuring ttk.Panedwindow and panes

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm experimenting with ttk.Panedwindow, but get errors with supposedly valid options. A few options work (e.g. `weight`), but most didn't. Please help me understand what's going on! I'm using python 3.6.3, tk 8.6, and ttk 0.3.1

#### Working Snippet

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# setup the panedwindow
root = tk.Tk()
paned_w = ttk.Panedwindow(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, width=300, height=300)
paned_w.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

# setup the panels
left_p = ttk.Label(paned_w, background='red')
right_p = ttk.Label(paned_w, background='yellow')
paned_w.add(left_p, weight=1)
paned_w.add(right_p, weight=3)

root.mainloop()
```

#### Panedwindow "unknown option"

If I try to change the sashwidth of the Panedwindow:

```
paned_w = ttk.Panedwindow(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, width=300, height=300, sashwidth=20)
```

I get an "unknown option" error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "panedwindow.py", line 6, in <module>
paned_w = ttk.Panedwindow(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, width=300, height=300, sashwidth=20)
  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 956, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::panedwindow", kw)
  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 559, in __init__
tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2293, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-sashwidth"
```

#### Child panel "unknown option"

The same error occurs if I try to configure child panels in the add() method:

```
paned_w.add(left_p, weight=1, minsize=10)
```

Yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "panedwindow.py", line 12, in <module>
    paned_w.add(left_p, weight=1, minsize=10)
  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3817, in add
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'add', child) + self._options(kw))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-minsize"
```

#### Child panel "bad command"

Since it didn't work in the add() method, I tried configuring it separately:

```
paned_w.paneconfig(left_p, minsize=10)
```

This gives me a "bad command" error, despite the intellisense recognizing it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "panedwindow.py", line 15, in <module>
    paned_w.paneconfig(left_p, minsize=10)
  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3972, in paneconfigure
    self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: bad command "paneconfigure": must be add, configure, cget, forget, identify, insert, instate, pane, panes, sashpos, or state
```

The same error occurs even if I run it without any options.

Printing the output of paned_w.paneconfig() (without specifying a panel) gives me a TypeError, as I would expect, so clearly the command is available:

```
TypeError: paneconfigure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tagOrId'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong: you are using the ttk `PanedWindow` widget, and that widget doesn't support `sashwidth` option, nor the `minsize` option for the `paneconfigure` method. Those are both only supported by the tkinter `PanedWindow` widget.

In other words, you seem to be relying on the documentation for the tkinter `PanedWindow` widget, but are actually using the ttk `PanedWindow` widget. Those two widgets have a similar look and feel, but the way you configure them are quite different.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of little oversight I feared. Thank you, I'll take another look at the documentation and make sure they match up!

Comment: I just found the tiny difference in the existence of the `insert` method between these both classes. Is there any chance (or effort known to you) that the APIs of tk and ttk will eventually be more coherent in the future?

Comment: @Wolf: I seriously doubt the API will ever change. Tkinter takes backwards compatibility very seriously.